# How to know what material shower floor is made of and what cleaning products to use on it?

Tags: cleaning, home, bathroom, house-cleaning

I have a shower in a new house, and the floor of it is dirty. If I google "how to clean shower floor" the answers I get largely depend on the type of floor. I have no idea what the floor is made of (it's uniform white plastic-y material).

**My Question Is:**

How do I go about figuring out what material the floor is? Once I get some insight into this, I can approach figuring out how to clean this material.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a *new* house, you should be able to contact the contractor who built it and ask.  Presumably, however, it's just "new to you" and you don't have that option.  We'll start with the likely possibilities: fiberglass, plastic of one sort or another, tile, epoxy/stone (aka engineered stone), or stainless steel -- those pretty well cover the range for no-tub showers built since the 1970s.  Bare natural stone is quite uncommon; concrete is very rare.

Simply put, you should be able to distinguish these by eye or feel -- or anyone experienced in home construction can, at the least.  The ones that are most similar are fiberglass and molded plastic, but those need similar care so almost don't matter.

Comment: The only advice I would add is to tap the material with your fingernails. Fiberglass and plastig produce a typical plasticy sound, while metal and enemailed metal produce a typical metallic sound. Tiles and epoxy are harder to tell by this method, but at least tiles should be easily distinguishable by sight.

Comment: Though possibly more expensive, showers can also be constructed out of solid surface materials like Corian.